# Blazor rendering twice when Task with IJSRuntime method is called

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor-client-side

I've got this test program I'm building to learn Blazor WASM, and I've built a generic table that takes a render fragment that runs a function on a given row. This function is just a simple JS alert that shows the details of a field of the specified row.

My problem is that this call causes the UI to render twice (I don't want it to render at all). I have found a work around at the moment by using an override for ShouldRender() and switching the render boolean to false both before, and after the JS call. But, I don't really like this approach.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening? Can I avoid having to do this with a different approach?

Here's the method, It's in a parent component to the table. You can see the boolean being set twice. This matters because the Table can be sorted, and I lose the sort whenever the alert is clicked (If I don't set the boolean twice, that is. If I set it once before or after the JS call it re renders once, and if I don't set it at all it renders twice).

```
`private async Task HandleClick(WeatherForecast forcast)
{
    Render = false;
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", $"{forcast.TemperatureF}");
    Render = false;
}`
```

Here's the action that calls the method

```
<button @onclick="@(() => SelectedItem.InvokeAsync(item))">@renderFragment</button>

@typeparam GenericType
@code {
[Parameter] public EventCallback<GenericType> SelectedItem { get; set; }
[Parameter] public RenderFragment renderFragment { get; set; }
[Parameter] public GenericType item { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the table where the button is clicked.

```
@using System.ComponentModel;
@using System.Reflection;

@typeparam GenericType

@if (Items == null)
{
    <img src="https://media4.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif" />
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                @foreach (var prop in Props)
                {
                    //Find the displayname, if it exists.
                    var name = PDesctirptions.Find(prop.Name, true)?.DisplayName ?? prop.Name;

                    <td @onclick="@(() => OrderBy(prop.Name))">@name</td>
                }

                @* if we have actions, show them. *@
                @if(ActionFragment != null)
                {
                    <td>Actions</td>
                }

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                <tr>

                    @foreach (var p in Props)
                    {
                        //Get's the property value of the item to display in the table.
                        <td>@item.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(item).ToString()</td>
                    }

                    @if (ActionFragment != null)
                    {
                        <td>@ActionFragment(item)</td>
                    }

                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>

}

@code {

    private bool desc = false;
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<GenericType> Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<GenericType> ActionFragment { get; set; }
    private Type T = typeof(GenericType);
    private PropertyInfo[] Props { get; set; }
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection PDesctirptions { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        Props = T.GetProperties();
        PDesctirptions = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(T);

    }


    void OrderBy(string name)
    {
        PropertyDescriptor pDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(T).Find(name, true);

        if (desc)
        {
            Items = Items.OrderBy(d => pDescriptor.GetValue(d)).ToList();
            desc = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Items = Items.OrderByDescending(d => pDescriptor.GetValue(d)).ToList();
            desc = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a visualization of the table, if it helps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBn2U.png)